# How do I add arrows into ol list?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

What I'm trying to create

[image]

My code

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
   <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: So anything you tried so far?

Comment: please delete your other duplicate question - no need to ask the same question twice

Answer (score 0):

Can't really add arrows into the bullets container, you wrap bullets into inlining around the arrows inside another container

```html
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <style type='text/css'>
.controls {

  position:relative;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #33333340;
  padding-top:10px;
}

.controls a.carousel-control-prev,
.controls a.carousel-control-next {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 22px;
  height: 21px;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon, .carousel-control-prev-icon {
  width:12px;
}
.carousel-indicators{
  list-style:none;
  color:black;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  display:inline-block;
  width:6px;
  height:6px;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  border-radius:12px;
  background:#eee;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}

.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background:#333;
  border:1px solid #333;
}
 .carousel-indicators li.active:after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 1px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    height: 22px;
    background: #333;
    
    display: block;
    margin-top: -8px;
 }

 </style>

 <div class='controls'>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"> 
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the indicators. I need to place the arrows

Comment: which carousel plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap carousel https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: Think that should do it?